# Weird problem with LaTeX/excel2latex

Tags: packages, compiling, excel2latex

I try to use `excel2latex` for converting excel tables into LaTeX. Here is the simple code I am using:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
\toprule
1     & 4     & 6     & 8 \\
\midrule
-53   & 9     & 10    & 10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

basically, when I copy the LaTeX code from `excel2latex` add-in and paste it in my LaTeX code, I get tons of errors[image: error list] but if I remove the last two lines and type it manually, it work.

Comment: Your given code runs perfect on my system (MiKTeX). Can you add the two lines causing the errors? It seems to be a code problem. You seems to have a special character in your excel style sheet that can't be converted correctly. Can you delete this character in your excel file?

Comment: `^^@` represents ASCII "NUL" (byte 0); from the form of the error lines it seems that line 29 contains a row of NULs.

Comment: @egreg Looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: Are you using OS X by any chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX shows `^^@`, it wants to represent the ASCII character `NUL` (byte 0). Judging from the error messages, it seems that your editor has inserted a row consisting of `NUL` characters.

As a protection against this kind of invisible characters, LaTeX declares that `^^@` (or `NUL`) is invalid if found in the input file.

Check your file and zap the offending characters.